# A interface IActionResult do asp.net.core.mvc serve pra exatamente o que?

Tags: c#, .net, asp-net-core

Estou aprendendo a fazer web api em C# e fiz um controller que tem um método POST que recebe um dado e faz uma regra de negócio na api, podendo retornar um BadRequest, um Ok ou um StatusCode dependendo do dado que vier do frontend.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EfetuarLogin([FromBody] LoginRequisicaoDto requisicao){
        ...
```

O LoginRequisicaoDto nada mais é que uma dto com login e senha, e 'requisicao' é onde foi guardado os dados recebidos pra ser usado, como se a requisicao fosse uma instância desse dto (por exemplo pra validar o login e a senha, ou certificar que não são nulos).

A pergunta é: não entendi o porque de ser um IActionResult como tipo de retorno, esse método EfetuarLogin() poderia ter outro tipo de retorno? Ou por ter várias possibilidades de retorno o IActionResult é o que precisa?

Obrigado e até mais!

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia é retornar os dados para o cliente sem considerar erros ou exceções e códigos HTTP (como 404, 200, 201, etc..) faria sentido, ainda que eu não entenda como uma boa prática.

Este endpoint que você demonstra (EfetuarLogin), recebe os dados do usuário, se os dados do usuário não estiverem corretos, ele terá que retornar um `404 - NotFound`, por exemplo, já se estiverem corretos, terá que retornar um `200 - Ok`.

Vale ressaltar que existe uma diferença entre utilizar IActionResult e ActionResult.

A interface **IActionResult** tem retornos mais amplos, que inclui qualquer código que implemente esta interface.

**ActionRetult** é limitada somente às classes que estendem a classe abstrata de ActionResult. (Você também pode customizar, a diferença é a herança múltipla que a interface permite e uma extensão de classe, não).

Answer (score 1):

Todos os métodos públicos de uma classe `MyClass : Controller` são chamados de "Actions", e devolvem qualquer tipo de dado que seja definido no retorno do metódo à requisição, como por exemplo `public List<MinhaLista>`.

Porém .NET  inclui várias classes `Result`. O padrão do `.NET framework` é a classe `abstrata` "ActionResult", que representa diferentes tipos de retorno pré-definidos, como `HTML`, `JSON`, `HttpUnauthorizedResult` e etc.

`.NET CORE` adotou como retorno padrão a interface `IActionResult`, o que te habilita a, além de retornar implementações padrão, retornar sua própria classe customizada `Result` que herde de `IActionResult`.